# Bolt CMS: Can routing.yml Accept Paths with Percent Sign?

Tags: bolt-cms

With Bolt CMS, I am trying to create routes for URIs like `/information-d%27expédition` but the percent sign (%) seems to be not accepted even if I tried putting the path value in quotes. Requesting that URI in the browser would just point me to the 404 page.

Here is the definition I have in mind for routing.yml:

```
shipping-info-fr:
  path: "/fr/information-d%27expédition"
  defaults:
    _controller: controller.frontend:template
    template: shipping-info.twig
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bolt (Symfony) routing component accepts unicode and special characters and encodes them itself, so there is no need to worry about percent-encoding.
Another point is, that `'` character is considered as "URL safe", so there is no need to percent-encode it anyways.

Read more here, if you want: https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

So, completely fine solution for your particular case is:

```
shipping-info-fr:
  path: "/fr/information-d'expédition"
  ...
```